# R Create new variable with conditional statement on first occurrence of value by grouping variable

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have the following dataframe with multiple task scores per user:

```
sampDF<-structure(list(User = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = 
c("A1", 
"A2"), class = "factor"), Task.Name = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 4L), .Label = c("T1", "T2", "T3", "T4"), class = "factor"), 
Max.Score = c(0.93, 0.95, 0.78, 0.87, 0.96)), class = "data.frame", row.names = 
c(NA, 
-5L))
```

I want to calculate a new variable (`Score.Plus5`) that adds a constant value (0.05) to the `Max.Score` value only if the value is `<0.90` and only to the first value `<0.90` per `User`, otherwise I want the original `Max.Score` value.

I attempted the following with `dplyr`:

```
sampDF2 <- sampDF %>% 
group_by(User) %>%
arrange(User, Max.Score) %>%
mutate(Score.Plus5 = ifelse(first(Max.Score <0.90), Max.Score + 0.05, 
Max.Score))
```

This results in repeats of either the `Max.Score` value plus the constant or the original `Max.Score` for each ID.

The result I want is:

```
sampDF3<-structure(list(User = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = 
c("A1", 
"A2"), class = "factor"), Task.Name = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 4L), .Label = c("T1", "T2", "T3", "T4"), class = "factor"), 
Max.Score = c(0.93, 0.95, 0.78, 0.87, 0.96), Score.Plus5 = c(0.93, 
0.95, 0.83, 0.87, 0.96)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

What would be the most efficient way to achieve this result with either `dplyr` or `data.table`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `data.table` solution

```r
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(sampDF)
dt[, Score.Plus5 := 
     ifelse(1:.N == 1 & Max.Score < .9, Max.Score + .05, Max.Score), 
   by = User]
dt
#R    User Task.Name Max.Score Score.Plus5
#R 1:   A1        T1      0.93        0.93
#R 2:   A1        T2      0.95        0.95
#R 3:   A2        T1      0.78        0.83
#R 4:   A2        T3      0.87        0.87
#R 5:   A2        T4      0.96        0.96
```

The code assumes that the data is sorted within each `User` to start with. Otherwise call `setkeys` assuming that `Task.Name` can be sorted in alphanumeric order (which I gather is the ordering you use).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `dplyr::first` is right choice in your case as if `first` value is less than `0,90` than it will be `true` all rows of that group. Hence, better you can use `row_number() == 1`. Hence the solution will be as:

```
library(dplyr)
sampDF %>% 
  group_by(User) %>%
  arrange(User, Max.Score) %>%
  mutate(Score.Plus5 = ifelse(row_number()==1 & Max.Score <0.90, Max.Score + 0.05, 
                Max.Score))

# # A tibble: 5 x 4
# # Groups: User [2]
#   User   Task.Name Max.Score Score.Plus5
#   <fctr> <fctr>        <dbl>       <dbl>
# 1 A1     T1            0.930       0.930
# 2 A1     T2            0.950       0.950
# 3 A2     T1            0.780       0.830
# 4 A2     T3            0.870       0.870
# 5 A2     T4            0.960       0.960
```

Comment: Or `library(data.table);setDT(sampDF)[Max.Score == min(Max.Score) & Max.Score < 0.90, Max.Score := Max.Score + 0.05, User]`

Answer (score 0):

> adds a constant value (0.05) to the `Max.Score` value only if the value is `<0.90` and only to the first value `<0.90` per `User`

I'd do a non-equi join...

```
library(data.table)
setDT(sampDF)

sampDF[, v := Max.Score]
sampDF[.(u = unique(User), s = 0.9), on=.(User == u, Max.Score <= s), mult="first", 
  v := v + 0.05][]

   User Task.Name Max.Score    v
1:   A1        T1      0.93 0.93
2:   A1        T2      0.95 0.95
3:   A2        T1      0.78 0.83
4:   A2        T3      0.87 0.87
5:   A2        T4      0.96 0.96
```

---

I am posting since the other answers treat

> only to the first value `<0.90` per `User`

as if it's

> only to the first value per `User` if that first value `<0.90`

even though generally they are not the same. (One special case where they are the same is if Max.Score is guaranteed to be increasing per User.)